# Image Lightbox component for react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Is there a light box component that works with react navigation?

I tried [react-native-lightbox](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-lightbox) but it requires the Navigator instance which isn't handily available when you use react-navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `withNavigation` to make sure it always gets passed in.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/with-navigation.html